# Python basic graphing of data using log vs log of the data

Tags: python, math, graphing

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7d8g.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjjer.png)

Trying to graph this data scaled by log but something is going wrong, it should look more exponential. Any ideas?

Thank you!!

I'm obviously new so I'm not sure what to do.I've tried different functions to no avail. Any help is much appreciated!
I think I might be scaling the axis not the data..

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/i76590576/edit) your question and replace the images with [properly formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) text. See: [*How to ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to use code and/or data when it's within images, so here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# exponential data
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {"x": [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000],
     "y": [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000]}
)
# make a scatterplot with a linear scale on both the x and y axis
plt.scatter(data.x, data.y)
plt.show()
```

[image: linear linear scale]

```
# plot with a log scale on the x axis
plt.scatter(data.x, data.y)
plt.xscale("log")
plt.show()
```

[image: log linear scale]

```
# plot with a log scale on the x and y axis
plt.scatter(data.x, data.y)
plt.xscale("log")
plt.yscale("log")
plt.show()
```

[image: log log scale]

It appears to be the case (though I can't tell for sure!) that your data is indeed exponential in both the x and y direction, so when you plot it with a log log scale, it just looks normal. This is normal. If you plot it with another scale (e.g. the log linear scale, as above) you will see the exponential-ness of the data and everything will click into place.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are just requirements with no effort or specific issue(s)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean @DavidMakogon. Can you be more specific by what you mean by "just requirements"?

Comment: I usually work from the premise that my role is to answer questions, and the moderators to moderate. I don't think it is my place to say if the question should be answered. And when the question is easy to answer, it's like, why not answer?

Comment: It has nothing to do with something being easy or hard to answer. As for "just requirements" - the OP posted what they want, along with an *image* of text, with no other details, no debugging, nothing - just "I want a graph scaled by log" - that's a requirement, with nothing else aside from an image of some data and an image of some dataframe text that has no context. 1) the OP needs to fix this to be readable text and 2) the OP needs to show *all relevant details* along with problems they are running into.

Comment: Ah I understand what you mean now! Apologies for the confusion